# IEEE Decimal to Binary Conversion

Tags: ieee-754, ieee

I would like to convert $14.83984375$ to Binary using IEEE 754 with 32 bits.

The true solution is: $01000001011011010111000000000000$.
But I do not get it.

My solution is: 
1. the sign is positive: 0 
2. 14 in binary equals $1110$
 $0.83984375$ equals $110101100...0$ 
3. So the exponent is 3 and we get: $3+127 = 10000010$ in bits

So if we put that together we get 
$0 10000010 110110101100...0$

The failure is, that I have $0.83984375$ equals $110101100...0$ and the solution says $0.83984375$ equals $110101110...0$.

Where does the $1$ come from?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't [convert 0.83984375](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) correctly; it is 0.11010111.